# How java knows which method to invoke?

Tags: java

I'am a complete noob to programming and trying hard to make sense of how coding and programming works.

So I was reading about polymorphism and dynamic binding and I think I understand it now (I hope) but what I didn't understand is why

```
AutoClosable ac = new PrintWriter(file);
```

shows lesser methods for execution when I use the dot operator than when I use dot operator on

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
```

What I'm trying to ask here is, that when the Actual Type is PrintWriter then I should get all the methods available in PrintWriter when I use the dot with "pw." it shouldn't matter what the Declared type is as dynamic binding should show me all the methods according to the Actual Type but that doesn't seems the case here. And this is not making sense to me.

However, if I use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> arList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then when I use arList. or list. then it shows all the same methods. And this is not making sense to me.
I hope I'm able to make myself clear about what Question/Confusion I have.

Comment: If you declare a variable of type `AutoClosable` then the compiler will treat it as if it holds an `AutoClosable`, so you can call `AutoClosable` methods on it. Why declare a variable of type `AutoClosable` if you don't want it treated as an `AutoClosable`?

Comment: The only reason to upcast to a supertype / interface is to use the generic interface of that supertype. That generic interface has a strictly smaller amount of methods / fields at the same access level. That ac field may also hold any other instance of `AutoClosable` after all.

Comment: In this case you'd **never** upcast to it, as it is a marker interface that is specific for semi-automated resource handling, specifically for the **try-with-resources** construction. And, while we're at it, nowadays you can also use `var` as in `try (var printWriter = new PrintWriter(file)) { /* code */ }`

Answer (score 1):

It's showing fewer methods for `ac` because its type is declared as `AutoCloseable` and not `PrintWriter`. In this case, a `PrintWriter` is assigned to it, but you could have a situation where an object of some other class is assigned to it too, like this.

```
AutoCloseable ac;
if (condition) ac = new PrintWriter(file);
else ac = new AutoCloseableImpl(); //where AutoCloseableImpl implements AutoCloseable
```

Here, you don't know that `ac` will necessarily be a `PrintWriter`. That's why the compiler only lets you access the methods that it knows for sure `ac` has - the ones declared in `AutoCloseable`.